# Работа с вложеными векторами

Tags: c++, vector

Пытаюсь разобраться с векторами (изучаю плюсы)
необходимо создать в классе вложеные вектор со следующей структурой.
пример из пхп

```
$array [i][0] = "head";
$array [i][1] = "text";
```

Инициирую с++

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> in_queue;
```

теперь необходима функция, принимающая 2 параметра и добавляющая в ввектор.

```
Не работает    
void add_in_queue(std::string &head, std::string &command) {
    in_queue.push_back(head, command);
}
```

И слудующая функция которя берет данные из вектора и затем стирает их.

```
Это еще не реализовал, так как заглох на этапе выше.
void job_in_queue(void) {
int i = 0;
while(true){
    head = in_queue[i][0];
    text = in_queue[i][1];
    in_queue.erase(i);
    function(head ,text );
    ++i;
    }
}
```

Как правильно реализовать подобный класс?

Comment: "Не работает" не является описанием проблемы

Comment: бьет ошибку что нельзя передавать в push_back 2 аргумента, но я не понимаю как по другому добавить в вектор.

Comment: Если загляните в документацию к `push_back`, то увидите, что этот метод принимает только один аргумент. ¿Что тут непонятного?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В функцию `push_back` нужно передавать только один параметр, и именно того типа, который указан в угловых скобках, а именно `std::vector<std::string>`. Поэтому вам надо сначала создать новый вложенный вектор, и уже его передать в функцию, а не пихать туда строки.

```
in_queue.push_back(std::vector<std::string>({head, command}));
```

Здесь происходит следующее: конструируется вектор, который сразу заполняется элементами с помощью `initializer_list`. Вектор передается в функцию `push_back`, которая добавляет его в корневой вектор.

Теперь про вторую часть, а именно про удаление элементов из вектора. При удалении надо не забывать, что те элементы, которые раньше находились после удаляемого, сдвигаются влево. Также обратите внимание, что функция `erase`  принимает не индекс, а итератор удаляемого элемента. Вот так будет правильно:

```
void job_in_queue(void) {
int i = 0;
for (auto it = in_queue.begin(); it != in_queue.end();)
{
    head = *it[0];
    text = *it[1];
    function(head ,text );
    it = in_queue.erase(it):
}
```

А ещё есть хороший ресурс по c++, где ко многим классам приведены примеры использования:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase

Comment: Компилировал в голове, так что если где-то опечатки, то поправьте.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я пока невидел ваш вариант сделал енмного по другому вторую часть.
size_vector = in_queue.size(); 
if (size_vector >= 1) {
function(in_queue[0][0],in_queue[0][1]);
in_queue.erase(in_queue.begin());
}
т.к. функция работает в отдельном потоке в вечном цикле. а in_queue меняет отдельный поток

Comment: В принципе так тоже должно работать, но если у вас один поток записывает в вектор, а другой читает, то надо защитить его мьютексом.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, буду изучать.